# AngularJs - ngTagsInput autocomplete should only show the matched result

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I am using the directive [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) for tag input in my AngularJs app. So far it works fine but I have been trying to show the matched result of autocomplete to be highlighted and appear on the top, removing all those unmatched.

I followed [this example](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos) but all to vain as it only makes the matched item bold.

Can somebody please point out what am i missing?

```js
$http.get(baseURL + '/misc/getAllSearchTags?token=' + token)
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.tagsList = response.data.data;
  });

$scope.tags = [];
$scope.loadtags = function($query) {
  return $scope.tagsList;
};
```

```css
.tag-template .left-panel {
  float: left;
}

.tag-template .left-panel img {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.tag-template .right-panel {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.autocomplete-template .left-panel {
  float: left;
}

.autocomplete-template .left-panel img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.autocomplete-template .right-panel {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.autocomplete-template .right-panel span:first-child {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.autocomplete-template .right-panel span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.autocomplete-template .right-panel span:last-child {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <tags-input ng-model="tags" display-property="name" placeholder="Add a Tag" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false">
    <auto-complete source="loadtags($query)" min-length="0" load-on-focus="true" load-on-empty="true" max-results-to-show="100" template="../retailerManagement/views/autoCompleteTemplate.html"></auto-complete>
  </tags-input>

</div>



//
<!--autoCompleteTemplate-->

<html>

<body>

  <div class="autocomplete-template">
    <div class="left-panel">

    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
      <span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize your $scope.loadtags function to return only the results that match the query. You need to filter $scope.tagsList in that function and return the filtered list.